# Azure SQL: join of 2 tables with 2 unicode fields returns empty when matching records exist

Tags: unicode-string

I have a table with a few key columns created with nvarchar(80) => unicode.
I can list the full dataset with SELECT * statement (Table1) and can confirm the values I need to filter are there.
However, I can't get any results from that table if I filter rows by using as input an alphabet char on any column.
Columns in table1 stores values in cyrilic characters.

I know it must have to do with character encoding => what I see in the result list is not what I use as input characters.
Unicode nvarchar type should resolve automatically this character type mismatch.

What do you suggest me to do in order to get results?

Thank you very much.

Paulo

Comment: apologies for the headline of my question which is not accurate to the body of my question. The issue is still there though with joining it with another table.

Comment: Post a repro so we have a better chance to help you?